# FLUTTER : How to make container size of children

Tags: flutter, dart

By definition, a container with children grows enough to show them. In this example that I am developing, I am not able to make the container fit the size of the children, I have to hardcode the Weight and Height, both, otherwise the container disappear (is the one with a red background, I put the whole code so you can copy-paste but it is only that one that I can not control the behaviour).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:littlebusiness/logic/Category.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class FormCategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormCategoryPageState createState() => _FormCategoryPageState();
}

class _FormCategoryPageState extends State<FormCategoryPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<RadioModel> sampleData = new List<RadioModel>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(true, 'A', 0xffe6194B));
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(false, 'B', 0xfff58231));
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(false, 'C', 0xffffe119));
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(false, 'D', 0xffbfef45));
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(true, 'A', 0xffe6194B));
    sampleData.add(new RadioModel(false, 'B', 0xfff58231));
  }

  String _name;

  Color _color;

  String _selectedValue;

  void addCategory(Category cat) {
    Hive.box('categories').add(cat);
  }

  void getColor(String value) {
    _selectedValue = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PERFORMANCE'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
//                  hintText: 'Enter your email',
                    labelText: 'Name',
                  ),
                  onSaved: (value) => _name = value,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter some text';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 320,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: sampleData.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                sampleData.forEach(
                                    (element) => element.isSelected = false);
                                sampleData[index].isSelected = true;
                              });
                            },
                            child: RadioItem(sampleData[index]),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                  child: Text('Add New Contact'),
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
//                  final newContact = Contact(_name, int.parse(_age));
//                  addContact(newContact);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RadioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final RadioModel _item;
  RadioItem(this._item);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 35.0,
            width: 35.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
                height: 25.0,
                width: 25.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(_item.colorCode),
                  borderRadius:
                      const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(15)),
                )),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                  width: 3.0,
                  color: _item.isSelected
                      ? Color(_item.colorCode)
                      : Colors.transparent),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(25)),
            ),
          ),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RadioModel {
  bool isSelected;
  final String buttonText;
  final int colorCode;
  RadioModel(this.isSelected, this.buttonText, this.colorCode);
}
```

This is the actuar result: 
[image]
Anyone knows why it is happening that? I am lost, and giving a with of double.infinity does not work... 
Thanks!

Comment: try setting only width of the container to MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, and put shrinkWrap true on the ListView.builder, and see if it solves the problem and tell me the if it works to post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using fixed values on wisth and height , you can use relative values to device by using

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

you can also use them like

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5 
which means 50% of the device screen

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You have to specified both width and height because your Listview is a child of a `Column` and a `Row`

You can replace your `Listview` by a `Row` of `RadioItem` in a `SingleChildScrollView`

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      var childs = <Widget>[];
      for (var item in sampleData) {
        childs.add(RadioItem(item));
      }
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: childs,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: That does not work and hides the entire Container (the red and his Childrens), and the answer to this behaviour and the solution is what I am looking for :(

Comment: @kike try the solution I put in the comment on your question, it must work

Answer (score 0):

Use IntrinsicHeight/IntrinsicWidth:

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Container(
    child: // children
  ),
)
```

```dart
IntrinsicWidth
  child: Container(
    child: // children
  ),
)
```